# I have an issue with PHP page / PostgreSQL

Tags: php, postgresql

I am trying to run a query in my PHP-file and it gives me an error, however this query works fine when I run it directly in PostgreSQL:

```
$query = 'SELECT o.nro, o.pvm, o.aika, o.koti, o.vieras, o.tulos, o.huom, 
o.yleisö, o.sarja, t1.nimi as PT1, t2.nimi as pt2, t3.nimi as lt1, t4.nimi 
as t2
FROM ottelut o, tuomari t1, tuomari t2, tuomari t3, tuomari t4
WHERE o.pt1 = t1.id
AND o.pt2 = t2.id
AND o.lt1 = t3.id
AND o.lt2 = t4.id
AND o.sarja='rs' 
ORDER BY o.nro'
;
```

Comment: change `'rs'` to `"rs"`

Comment: tried already, no different

Comment: It would help to post the error message as well so we have better idea of what is wrong.

Comment: if I put just 'rs' then:
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'rs' (T_STRING) in C:\wamp64\www\Liiga\ottelut.php on line 41
(line 41 =    and o.sarja='rs)'
if I put "rs" then:
Warning: pg_query(): Query failed: ERROR: column reference &quot;rs&quot; is ambiguous LINE 7: and o.sarja=&quot;rs&quot; ^ in C:\wamp64\www\Liiga\ottelut.php on line 44
(line 44 =$result = pg_query($query) or die('Query failed: ' . pg_last_error());)

Comment: Sorry I copied that line 41 incomplete, for real it is :and o.sarja='rs'

Comment: The "rs" suggestion is because by using single quotes you are actually breaking out of the string you are defining in $query, and generating a syntax error. Using double-quotes keeps you in the string. This is absolutely necessary.

Comment: Please edit the question with the exact error text, don't leave it in the comments where it is difficult to find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a syntax error because you are breaking out of the string by trying to use single quotes inside a single-quoted string. You are also reusing the `t2` alias. Originally in your `SELECT` list and then as a table name.

Try the following query:

```php
$query = 'SELECT o.nro, o.pvm, o.aika, o.koti, o.vieras, o.tulos, o.huom, '.
                'o.yleisö, o.sarja, t1.nimi as PT1, t2.nimi as pt2, '.
                't3.nimi as lt1, t4.nimi as t4nimi '.
         'FROM ottelut o, tuomari t1, tuomari t2, tuomari t3, tuomari t4 '.
         'WHERE o.pt1 = t1.id '.
           'AND o.pt2 = t2.id '.
           'AND o.lt1 = t3.id '.
           'AND o.lt2 = t4.id '.
           "AND o.sarja='rs' ".
         'ORDER BY o.nro';
```